# Installing mysql gem on rubinius

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux, fedora, rubinius

I have tried installing MYSQL gem on fedora using rubinius but it keeps throwing failed to build gem's native extension and that I should install development tools first.

I am on Fedora 22 and I already have mysql-devel library installed. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don’t have `gcc` et al installed yet. The “development tools” being referred to is likely the yum/dnf group. You can install a slew of build tools by following [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1344/101165). But now that we’re on Fedora 22, use `dnf` instead of `yum`.

So, in short:

```
sudo dnf groupinstall 'Development Tools' 'Development Libraries'
```

Comment: It still fails, I even tried to specify the path but it fails. Is there a way to force the compiler to be clang instead of gcc?